# Python - Why doesn't this instance method need parentheses when called inside another instance method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know it's a noob question, but I'm trying to figure out why "self.update_count", doesn't need parentheses when its called from the 'create_widget' method. I've been searching, but can't find out why.

Please help.

```
# Click Counter
# Demonstrates binding an event with an event handler

from Tkinter import *

class Skeleton(Frame):
   """ GUI application which counts button clicks. """
   def __init__(self, master):
       """ Initialize the frame. """
       Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.grid()
       self.bttn_clicks = 0 # the number of button clicks
       self.create_widget()

   def create_widget(self):
       """ Create button which displays number of clicks. """
       self.bttn = Button(self)
       self.bttn["text"] = "Total Clicks: 0"
       # the command option invokes the method update_count() on click
       self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count
       self.bttn.grid()

   def update_count(self):
       """ Increase click count and display new total. """
       self.bttn_clicks += 1
       self.bttn["text"] = "Total Clicks: "+ str(self.bttn_clicks)

# main root = Tk() root.title("Click Counter") root.geometry("200x50")

app = Skeleton(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.update_count()
```

would be a call to the method, so

```
self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count()
```

would store the result from the method in `self.bttn`. However,

```
self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count
```

without the parens stores *the method itself* in `self.bttn`. In Python, methods and functions are objects that you can pass around, store in variables, etc.

As a simple example of this, consider the following program:

```
def print_decimal(n):
    print(n)

def print_hex(n):
    print(hex(n))

# in Python 2.x, use raw_input
hex_output_wanted = input("do you want hex output? ")

if hex_output_wanted.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
    printint = print_hex
else:
    printint = print_decimal

# the variable printint now holds a function that can be used to print an integer
printint(42)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function call but a reference storage inside a dictionary:

```
self.bttn["command"] = self.update_count 
// stores reference to update_count inside self.bttn["command"]
// invokable by self.bttn["command"]()
```

Most probably the Button object has the capability of calling this method upon certain interaction.

Comment: Thanks to you too. I get it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't called from that method. It's using a reference to the function, which the button will call later when it's clicked. You can think of it as a function's name being a reference to the code in that function; to call the function you apply the () operator.